# Conky seamod is not working properly

Tags: conky

I'm new to the forum and ubuntu.
I tried to run Conky Seamod, after some tweaks regarding the network, everything seems to work but except the rings not loading.
Can you help me?

I have just read your answer and I am attaching the script withkyrc_seamod and screenshot of my desktop.

```
--                               conkyrc_seamod
-- Date    : 04/23/2016
-- Author  : SeaJey and Maxiwell
-- Conky   : >= 1.10 
-- License : Distributed under the terms of GNU GPL version 2 or later
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

conky.config = {

    background = true,
    update_interval = 1,

    cpu_avg_samples = 2,
    net_avg_samples = 2,
    temperature_unit = 'celsius',

    double_buffer = true,
    no_buffers = true,
    text_buffer_size = 2048,

    gap_x = 20,
    gap_y = 40,
    minimum_width = 300, minimum_height = 900,
    maximum_width = 350,

    own_window = true,
    own_window_type = 'normal',
    own_window_transparent = true,
    own_window_argb_visual = true,
    own_window_class = 'conky-semi',
    own_window_hints = 'undecorated,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below',

    border_inner_margin = 0,
    border_outer_margin = 0,
    alignment = 'top_right',


    draw_shades = false,
    draw_outline = false,
    draw_borders = false,
    draw_graph_borders = false,

    override_utf8_locale = true,
    use_xft = true,
    font = 'caviar dreams:size=11',
    xftalpha = 0.5,
    uppercase = false,

-- Defining colors
    default_color = '#FFFFFF',
-- Shades of Gray
    color1 = '#DDDDDD',
    color2 = '#AAAAAA',
    color3 = '#888888',
-- Orange
    color4 = '#EF5A29',
-- Green
    color5 = '#77B753',
-- Loading lua script for drawning rings
    lua_load = '~/.conky/seamod/seamod_rings.lua',
    lua_draw_hook_pre = 'main',

};

--${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color1}${pre_exec lsb_release -d | cut -f 2} - $sysname $kernel
conky.text = [[
${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=bold}${color4}SYSTEM ${hr 2}
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color1}$sysname $kernel
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color1}Battery:  ${color3}${battery_bar 5,150 BAT0} ${color3}${battery_percent BAT0}%
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color1}Uptime: ${color3}$uptime

# Showing CPU Graph
${voffset 20}
${offset 125}${cpugraph cpu0 40,220 666666 666666 -0.3}${voffset -25}
${offset 90}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=bold}${color5}CPU
# Showing TOP 5 CPU-consumers
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color4}${top name 1}${alignr}${top cpu 1}%
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color1}${top name 2}${alignr}${top cpu 2}%
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color2}${top name 3}${alignr}${top cpu 3}%
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color3}${top name 4}${alignr}${top cpu 4}%
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color3}${top name 5}${alignr}${top cpu 5}%

#Showing memory part with TOP 5
${voffset 40}
${offset 90}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=bold}${color5}MEM
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color4}${top_mem name 1}${alignr}${top_mem mem_res 1}
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color1}${top_mem name 2}${alignr}${top_mem mem_res 2}
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color2}${top_mem name 3}${alignr}${top_mem mem_res 3}
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color3}${top_mem name 4}${alignr}${top_mem mem_res 4}
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=normal}${color3}${top_mem name 4}${alignr}${top_mem mem_res 5}

# Showing disk partitions: root, home and files
${voffset 12}
${offset 180}${color1}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}Disk Read: ${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}${color2}${diskio_read}
${offset 180}${color1}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}Disk Write: ${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}${color2}${diskio_write}
${voffset -30}
${offset 90}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=bold}${color5}DISKS
${offset 120}${diskiograph 40,220 666666 666666 -0.5}${voffset -30}
${voffset 20}
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Free: $color3${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}${fs_free /}${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Used: $color3${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}${fs_used /}
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Free: $color3${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}${fs_free /home}${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Used: $color3${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}${fs_used /home}
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Free: $color3${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}${fs_free /media/files}${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Used: $color3${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}${fs_used /media/files}

# Network data (my desktop have only LAN). ETHERNET ring is mostly useless but looks pretty, main info is in the graphs
${voffset 45}
${offset 200}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Lan IP: ${alignr}$color3${addr enp0s3} 
${offset 200}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Ext IP: ${alignr}$color3${execi 600 wget -q -O /dev/stdout http://checkip.dyndns.org/ | cut -d : -f 2- | cut -d \< -f -1} 
${offset 190}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}${alignr}$color3${execi 600 wget -q -O /dev/stdout https://www.dnsleaktest.com/ | grep from | grep -o '<p>.*<img' | grep -o '>.*<' | grep -oEi '[a-zA-Z0-9 ,]+'}

${voffset -60}
${offset 90}${font Ubuntu:size=11:style=bold}${color5}ETHERNET
${voffset 40}             
${offset 15}${color1}${font ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}Up: ${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}$color2${upspeed enp0s3} / ${totalup enp0s3}
${offset 15}${upspeedgraph enp0s3 40,320 4B1B0C FF5C2B 1280KiB -l}
${offset 15}${color1}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=bold}Down: ${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=10:style=normal}$color2${downspeed enp0s3} / ${totaldown enp0s3}
${offset 15}${downspeedgraph enp0s3 40,320 324D23 77B753 1280KiB -l}

${color4}${hr 2}




]];
```

[image: screenshot conky seamod]

Comment: Please, could you [edit] the question adding the content of the conky script and a screenshot of the way it appear in your desktop? It's difficult to help without further details.

Comment: sounds like a problem in the conky script you should be able to find it in .conky folder witch is a hidden folder in /home/usernamme so /home/username/.conky we will need to see it to help

Comment: @pier, hope you solved  the issue installing Lua, please let me know, I suggest to install  conky-manager too.

Comment: Thanks for your help solving the problem for me

Answer (score 2):

The reason for which your conky works partially with only missing of the rings should be that probably you have not installed Lua.

As you can see in my configuration rings works as Lua is installed.

[image]

[image]

you can check  Lua installation in this way from terminal:

```
dpkg-query -l | grep lua
lua -v
```

If not installed then you can install with:

```
sudo apt install lua5.3
```

I suggest also to install **conky manager 2.4** with this workaround working for
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS & 20.04 LTS

download first missing dependecy from here :

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/realpath/8.26-3ubuntu4

download conky manager from here:

https://github.com/teejee2008/conky-manager/releases/download/v2.4/conky-manager-v2.4-amd64.deb

install first missing dependency :

```
sudo dpkg -i realpath_8.26-3ubuntu4_all.deb
```

and then  conky-manager-v2.4

```
sudo dpkg -i conky-manager-v2.4-amd64.deb
```

At the end you will have conky-manager installed to easily handle and test your conky collection.

[image]